# If a button is disabled, the form is not submitted

Tags: php, html, forms, submit, form-submit

This code confirms the information that the user filled the form with.

On my first submit I use this code and it prevents the form from getting submitted twice:

```
<td width="30%" align="left">
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="OK" onclick="this.disabled=true; this.value='Sending...'; selectCarMakeModel.submit();"/>
</td>
```

But on the confirmation code, on my second submit, if I want to add "this.disable" in the onclick it wont work, not before or after the command, it just stays idle:

```
<form name="selectCarMakeModel" action="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>" method="post">
    <?
    foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="'. $key .'" value="'. myHTMLSpecialChars($val) .'">' . "\n";
    }
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="sticky" value="showForm">
    <input type="submit" name="goBack" value="No, Go Back">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Si, continue" onClick="this.form.sticky.value='continue'">
</form>
```

Thanks

Edit: Sorry, Sorry...I didnt ask it correctly, the first code Works ok, the problem is that in the second code if I click the submit button twice the form gets submitted twice, so I try to add the "this.disable" function, but on the second code wont work, it wont process if I add it and if I dont add it sometimes the form gets send twice.

Comment: This is 100% on the client and had nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: Seems pretty straight forward...you disable it so you can't submit it twice but your asking why you can't submit it again...re enable it?

Comment: Your HTML makes baby Tim Berners-Lee cry. Please don't use tables for layout, nonbreaking spaces for spacing, or presentational attributes.

Comment: I didnt ask correctly: the code on the first block, Works as intended. When I try to also add "this.disable" in the second block it wont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-enable after submission:

```
onclick="this.disabled=true; this.value='Sending...'; selectCarMakeModel.submit();this.disabled=false;"
```

That should set it up for next time.

Answer (score 2):

`disabled` elements **do not fire events**. You'd have to enable the property, then that will allow the event to fire.

Comment: my problem is that the form gets submited twice sometimes on the second code, but if I try to add the "this.disable" like I did on the first code it does not send the form.

Comment: why you dont send the form with `submit()` method and then  makes it disabled? have you tried this?

Comment: @jcslzr Do you mean say for example if someone double clicks? Is that what you're trying to prevent?

Comment: @jcslzr Have you tried `onclick="this.value='Sending...'; selectCarMakeModel.submit();this.disabled=true;`

Comment: @mattytommo, it does work on the first screen (top block of code), but on the second screen I still can submit twice, because if I disable the button like in the first code, it does not send it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to set what you want to submit as hidden, and then you can disable the submit after the 1st click, (submitting the hidden values). The user won't be able to submit twice and the values will be submitted